# Why does this function produce so many child processes?

Tags: c, process

I wrote this code in order to calculate the factorial of a number using processes and `pipe()`. I wanted to pass on the result from the child process to the child process. For example, to create calculate 5! the main which is the father sends the number 1 in the pipe. Then the first child is created and does 1*2, then it pushes in the pipe the number 2, the second child does 2*3 pushes the result in the pipe etc... Also, I use argv[1][0] thinking that we run the program like this (./ex3 5) where 5 is the number of which the factorial we would like to find. After running the program though, **I noticed that a lot of child process was created *(I only wanted 4)*. Why is that?**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int fd[2];
int w,count=2;

void child_creator(){
    pid_t child;
    child=fork();
    if (child==0) {
        close(fd[1]);
        read(fd[0],&w,sizeof(w));
        close(fd[0]);
        w=w*count;
        count++;
        printf("I am child %d , my father is %d , the prod is %d\n",getpid(),getppid(),w);
        sleep(1);

        close(fd[0]);
        write(fd[1],&w,sizeof(w));
        close(fd[1]);       
    }
}       

int main(int argc , char **argv){
    int fact=argv[1][0]-'0';
    pipe(fd);
    w=1;
    for (int i=0; i<fact-1; i++){
         printf("this is i %d\n", i);
        child_creator();
    }
    return 0;
}
```

After a suggested answer I tried this code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int fd[1000][2];
int w,count=1,j=0;

void child_creator(){
    pid_t child;
    j++;
    pipe(fd[j]);
    child=fork();
    if (child==0) {
        close(fd[j-1][1]);
        read(fd[j-1][0],&w,sizeof(w));
        close(fd[j-1][0]);
        w=w*count;
        printf("I am child %d , my father is %d , the prod is %d\n",getpid(),getppid(),w);
        sleep(1);

        close(fd[j-1][0]);
        write(fd[j][1],&w,sizeof(w));
        close(fd[j][1]);

        exit(0);        

    }

}       

int main(int argc , char **argv){
    int fact=argv[1][0]-'0';
    w=1;
    for (int i=0; i<fact-1; i++){ 
     count++;
     child_creator();
     sleep(2);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Because your children create their children too.

Comment: Both the parent and child continue executing the `for` loop.

Comment: @EugeneSh. How do I fix that and produce the same result?

Comment: @Barmar How do I prevent that but have the same result? why is that happening?

Comment: Many ways to do so. Simplest (but a bit ugly) would be to add a "is_child" flag that you set within the function and check in the `for` loop. better refactor it a bit.

Comment: @maverick98 Consider if 'child_creator(..)' returned the child pid, so in the outside loop: `if (child_creator() == 0) { break /* child doesn't get to loop again! */; }`. Does that show the flow better, and why the child is also running the "parents" loop? Many options to actually address such..

Comment: The child could exit instead of returning.

Comment: @Barmar When I used exit(0) at the end of if(child==0) the program did not run as expected

Comment: You have other problems. You're writing to `fd[1]` after you closed it earlier.

Comment: What's up with the screen shot?  Text is your friend.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both the parent and child are returning to the `for` loop in `main()`. Since the child doesn't need to do anything after it writes its result, it should just exit rather than returning.

You also have problems with your handling of the pipe file descriptors. You do `close(fd[1])` at the beginning of the child, but later try to `write(fd[1],&w,sizeof(w))`. You can't write to a closed FD. You don't need to close anything until the child is exiting, and exiting a process automatically closes all its files.

```
void child_creator(){
    pid_t child;
    child=fork();
    if (child==0) {
        read(fd[0],&w,sizeof(w));
        w=w*count;
        count++;
        printf("I am child %d , my father is %d , the prod is %d\n",getpid(),getppid(),w);
        sleep(1);
        write(fd[1],&w,sizeof(w));
        exit(0);   
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm also unsure about using the same pipe for every child. You can't be sure that they'll write and read in the desired order.

Comment: @maverick98 after your edit, your code still closes `fd[1]` before trying to write to it...

Comment: @MichaelBeer How can I fix that? I removed the close(fd[1]); but when I run the program it doesn't print anything at all

Comment: Declare an array of pipes, create a new pipe before each fork, and each child uses the appropriate pipe to communicate with the next one in the series.

Comment: @Barmar I tried what you said , but I think I am doing something wrong , I edited the post with the new code

Comment: `read(fd[j], ...)` should be `read(fd[j][0], ...)`, and similarly for all the other functions that use the pipes.

Comment: @Barmar Actually I made it work , everyone interested see the Edit

Comment: Post your final solution as an answer.